# How to solve $Mx=b$ where singular M but setting $x_n=0$ for some $x$ allows unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matlab

I want to solve $Mx=b$ where $M$ (concrete example below) is singular, but where I can arbitrarily set some $x_i=0$ .. in which case I believe there should be a unique solution for $x$? But how how do I obtain it? The concrete example I provide is a simple example but approach to solving will need to work for large matrices (working in Matlab).. I apologize if this turns out to be an elementary problem... it's troubling me.

$$
   M= \begin{bmatrix}
    2 & -1 & -1 \\
    1 & 0 & -1 \\
    1 & 1 & -2 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
 b=\begin{bmatrix}
     2 \\
     0 \\
    -2 \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: If $M$ is singular, then $Mx=\mathbf{0}$ has infinitely many solutions. Given any solution $x_b$ to $Mx=b$, then every vector of the form $x_b+x_0$, where $x_0$ is a solution to $Mx=b$, is also a solution. So $Mx=b$ must have either *no* solutions, or infinitely many solutions. It is *possible* that among those, there is one and only one solution that lies in a specific "coordinate subspace" obtained by specifying that some of the $x_i$ are equal to zero, but that need not be the case. To find it/them, add the equations $x_i=0$ and solve the new system.

Comment: Do you want to figure out which variables to set to zero _without_ solving the original system? Setting a variable to zero is equivalent to deleting the corresponding column of $M$, so without first computing the rref, you could try deleting columns until the resulting matrix has full rank.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SVD. Let $M = U \Sigma V^{T}$. Then if you consider the problem least squares problem

$$  \min_{x} \| Mx  - b\|_{2}^{2} $$

we get

$$  \| Mx - b\|_{2}^{2} = \|U^{T} (M VV^{T} x - b)\|_{2}^{2}  = \| \Sigma V^{T}x - U^{T}b\|_{2}^{2}$$

You can compute this like

$$ x^{*} = V \Sigma^{-1}U^{T}b $$

with

$$  \Sigma^{-1} = \begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}}& \sigma_{i}  \neq 0 \\ 0  & \textrm{ otherwise}        \end{cases} \end{align}$$

Your matrix is really ill-conditioned.

```
import numpy as np

M = np.array( [[ 2, -1, -1 ] , [1 , 0,-1] , [1, 1, -2] ])

b = np.array([2,1,-1])

Mstar = np.linalg.pinv(M)
xstar = np.dot(Mstar, b)

error = np.linalg.norm(np.dot(M,xstar) - b)
error


0.6030226891555274

np.linalg.cond(M)


1.2505769527845804e+16
```

If you check the singular values

```
U, S, Vt = np.linalg.svd(M)

S

array([3.31662479e+00, 1.73205081e+00, 2.65207573e-16])
```

The rank is $2$. You need to drop that last singular value.

Comment: We can also comment that this is equivalent to multiplying both sides by the pseudoinverse of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

So $Mx =b$ has infinitely many solutions. One approach is that you could find the least norm solution by multiplying both sides by the pseudoinverse of $M$.